# The meanning system memory specification for Ryzen

Tags: processor, memory

In the [official process specifications](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-5-3600#product-specs) of a processor such as AMD Ryzen™ 5 3600. There is an item titled **System Memory Specification** and it equals to 3200MHz. I know that is the frequency of system path and increasing that frequency means faster memory and system.

What **I don't know** about this specification, does it minimum requirement or maximum? In other words, suppose that there is RAM of just 3000MHz does it work with this system or not? on the other hand, suppose there is RAM of 4000 MHz too?

Finally, I don't want to over purchasing for something that may not work with the system or even the system will not get benefits from it.

Comment: Hi welcome to HW Recs! In general, we offer purchase recommendations for hardware rather than technical support or details which our sister site [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour) is usually better equipped for. If you are looking for purchasing RAM upgrades for Ryzen... this is considered on topic. Finally, you can purchase higher/lower rated frequency RAM for your system, but it will be negotiated to the default or lower speed unless you overclock the RAM up from the default negotiated speed.